# EditText and textView will not fit within layout bounds

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-linearlayout, android-xml

I'm building a gridView which replicates the basic functionality of a Launcher (it allows you to create new folders - and arrange them within the gridView).

My problem is I have a textView and an imageView (which should appear below the bottom most tile [it is either white or grey depending on how many times the add image button is clicked] in the screenshot below) however they are being pushed outside the bounds of the layout for some reason - and I'm having trouble identifying which one is causing this to occur.

I've tried many different combinations of height and width paramaters as well as trying Linear vs Relative layout for my innermost child layout - but I still can't seem to keep the textView and an imageView from being pushed outside the layout completely and I'm having a bit of trouble nailing down what exactly is causing it.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1.0" >

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/image_grid_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:background="@color/grid_background"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="2dip"
            android:numColumns="@integer/num_columns"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="2dip" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_part"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1.0" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_add_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:onClick="onClickAddImage"
                android:text="Add image" />

            <com.example.project.DeleteZone
                android:id="@+id/delete_zone_view"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/delete_zone" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/image_source_frame"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                     >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/sqwhite"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editText1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_below="@id/sqwhite"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" >

                        <requestFocus />
                    </EditText>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_below="@id/editText1"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `FrameLayout` is redundant as it only contains a `LinearLayout`, but more importantly it's set to `80dp` height. This means that anything beyond `80dp` will not be visible. Try setting it to `wrap_content`.

Comment: I updated my source and screenshot above... the tile now appears huge all of a sudden after changing that

Comment: Where is that grey box (I'm guessing this is the "tile" you keep talking about) coming from? I don't see it in your layout.

Comment: Sorry - it can be grey or white depending on how many times the Add Image button is clicked

Comment: any idea what might be causing the imageView to appear so large all of a sudden?

Comment: I'm not sure why it got so big since it's only set to 20x20dp

Comment: Any ideas? 

Also - you can probably solve this one as well... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913058/android-xml-layout-parameters-do-not-function-as-expected

Comment: Didn't take notice of this earlier, but the layout inside of the `FrameLayout` (used to be a `LinearLayout` but is now a `RelativeLayout`) is set to `fill_parent`. That doesn't work well. Basically you're telling the parent `FrameLayout` to base its size on its children, but telling the child `RelativeLayout` to base its size on its parent. Seriously just merge the two into one layout. You don't need the `FrameLayout` unless I'm missing something here.

Comment: I actually do need it - it's used in my java source: 


FrameLayout imageHolder = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.image_source_frame);

http://pastebin.com/aGb4dZx3